# Не конструируется std::istream_iterator для wchar_t | C++

Tags: c++, файлы, итераторы

Хочу посимвольно перебрать файл и поменять некоторые символы. Для этого использую такой код:

```
std::wifstream m_in;
std::wofstream m_out;

//....

using in_it = std::istream_iterator<wchar_t>;
using out_it = std::ostream_iterator<wchar_t>;

std::transform(in_it(m_in), in_it(), out_it(m_out), 
    [](wchar_t c) {
        
        return (c == 31 ? ';' : c);

    });
```

И компилятор ругается, что я не могу создать итератор для `std::wifstream`. Хотя у `std::wifstream` char_type - это wchar_t, и для итератора я указал wchar_t. Что не так я делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что первый аргумент шаблона `istream_iterator` и `ostream_iterator` - это тип, который будет извлекаться из потока, т.е. это может быть `int`, `double` или любой другой тип. А вот второй аргумент - это уже тип символов самого потока. Это может быть `char` или `wchar_t` и т.п. Значит итераторы нужно обьявлять так:

```
using in_it = std::istream_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t>;
using out_it = std::ostream_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t>;
```

Comment: Спасибо, задам смежный вопрос. Почему код выше (с учетом правок для wchar_t) в выходном файле все пишет в одну строку, хотя в исходном есть переносы строк

Comment: @ComeInRage Вроде и пробелы должен пропускать тоже. Извлечение данных из потока происходит также как и при использовании оператора `>>`. А значит пропускает все пробельные символы, в том числе и перевод строки.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Буду крайне признателен, если подскажете способ не пропускать спецсимволы и пробелы)

Comment: @ComeInRage Попробуйте использовать `istreambuf_iterator` вместо `istream_iterator`

Comment: Это как раз то, что нужно. Спасибо. Только никак не могу понять в чем разница между stream и streambuf. В документации написано, что stream реализованы с помощью streambuf. То есть все stream - это обертки вокруг streambuf, а сам streambuf - это обертка вокруг хранилища с данными файла? :/

Comment: @ComeInRage `istream_iterator` волнует тип, на который он указывает, т.е. в потоке может быть 2 числа, например `123 456`. Если через `istream_iterator` мы итерируемся по типу `int`, то по мению `istream_iterator` в потоке всего два элемента (наши два числа 123 и 456). `istreambuf_iterator` тип не волнует, он просто идет по буферу символ за символом. Вроде как-то так, но я могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T, class Сh = char, 
         class Traits = char_traits<Ch>, 
         class Diff = ptrdiff_t>
class istream_iterator{...};
```

Обратите внимание, что    его `char_type` то есть `Ch` по умолчанию есть `char`,  поэтому этот параметр шаблона нужно передать:

```
using in_it = std::istream_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t>;
using out_it = std::ostream_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t>;
```